# Como pegar o código fonte do Gmail usando Python3

Tags: python-3.x, email, request

Estou acessando o Email usando esse código q eu encontrei e adaptei:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

form_data = {'Email': 'exemplo@gmail.com', 'Passwd': 'senhaexemplo'}
post = "https://accounts.google.com/signin/challenge/sl/password"

def login(self):
    with requests.Session() as s:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get("https://mail.google.com").text, "html.parser")
        for inp in soup.select("#gaia_loginform input[name]"):
            if inp["name"] not in form_data:
                form_data[inp["name"]] = inp["value"]
        s.post(post, form_data)
        html = s.get("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox").text
        print(html)
```

Meu objetivo é pegar os Emails e printar na tela, com assunto e conteúdo, e eu sei como fazer isso usando certas tags do html... Mas para isso preciso do código fonte do site, e quando eu vou olhar o resultado do `print(html)` não vem com nenhuma tag, fica tudo comprimido... Algo assim:

```
{\"1\":\"be_35\",\"53908043\":0},{\"1\":\"be_36\",\"53908043\":0},{\"1\":\"be_30\",\"53908043\":0},{\"1\":\"be_31\",\"53908043\":0},{\"1\":\"be_169\",\"53908043\":0},{\"1\":\"su_ltz\"},{\"1\":\"ic_sspvcd\"},{\"1\":\"bu_wdtfsm\"},{\"1\":\"be_26\",\"53908043\":0},{\"1\":\"be_29\",\"53908043\":0},{\"1\":\"be_280\",\"53908043\":0},{\"1\":\"be_281\",\"53908043\":0},{\"1\":\"30\",\"53908046\":0},{\"1\":\"31\",\"53908043\":0},{\"1\":\"32\",\"53908046\":0},{\"1\":\"33\",\"53908046\":0},{\"1\":\"be_277\",\"53908043\":0},{\"1\":\"34\",\"53908045\":\"\"},{\"1\":\"be_278\",\"53908043\":0},{\"1\":\"35\",\"53908046\":0},{\"1\":\"be_275\",\"53908043\":0},{\"1\":\"be_276\",\"53908043\":0},{\"1\":\"be_273\",\"53908043\":1},{\"1\":\"38\",\"83947487\":{}},{\"1\":\"se_192\",\"53908045\":\"en,es,pt,ja,fr\"},{\"1\":\"be_274\",\"53908043\":0},{\"1\":\"39\",\"53908046\":0}
```

Como posso pegar o código fonte correto?

Comment: Não seria mais fácil utilizar [IMAP](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/imaplib.html) ou alguma API ao invés de montar um crawler?

Comment: Estou usando esse método para fins de estudo, procurar formas de resolver um problema sem o método mais fácil. Eu acho que o problema no meu caso é a encriptação json, posso estar enganado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não querendo chover no seu desfile, mas... Sites que usam AJAX não retornam o conteúdo no HTML, eles geram o conteúdo dinamicamente, depois da carga, usando Javascript. Você teria de usar uma solução radicalmente diferente, como PhantomJS, que efetivamente carrega todos os arquivos auxiliares da página e executa o código Javascript, para então analisar o DOM e extrair o conteúdo.

Comment: Obrigado! Esclareceu bastante, eu tenho pouca experiencia quando se trata de https e web.